# What are Luckys?

Tags: bag-it

For the silver ribbon in one of the levels where you need to crush stuff, it says I need to crush 6 Luckys.

What are Luckys? How can I best crush them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucky's are the green cereal boxes, like the ones shown below. When I got to that level, I had no idea what it was either so I started trying to crush everything and I got the silver ribbon after crushing six of these guys. I'm sure you already know how to crush them :)

[image: BagIt]